# Java cant adding object in list without generic

Tags: java, generics

I have those classes.

```
public class Flight {
    public List<FlightOffer> flightOffers;
}

public class Hotel<T> {
    public List<HotelOffer> hotelOffers;
    public T address
}

public class FlightOffer extends BaseOffer{
}

public class HotelOffer extends BaseOffer{
}

public class BaseOffer{
    public String id;
}
```

flightOffers and hotelOffers returns a list.

```
Flight flightObject = new Flight();
flightObject.flightOffers.add(new BaseOffer()); // not working 
//(add (FlightOffer) List  cannot be applied to (BaseOffer))

Hotel hotelObject = new Hotel<String>();
hotelObject.hotelOffers.add(new BaseOffer()); // working
```

but if i convert `Flight` to `Flight<T>` its working, why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`List<FlightOffer> flightOffers` defines quite clearly what you can add to the list: instances of `FlightOffer`. `flightOffers.add(new BaseOffer());` hence can't work since a `BaseOffer` *is not* a `FlightOffer`.

So why does `hotelOffers.add(new BaseOffer());` work? Because you are disabling generic type checks by using the raw type `Hotel` in `Hotel hotelObject = new Hotel<String>();`.

You should get a warning about that as well which conveys another lesson: don't ignore the warnings. The compiler doesn't know that something *will* fail but more often than not it "guesses" correctly and warns you about that.

**Edit:**

Note what the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) states on raw types (in the first box of section 4.8):

> Another implication of the rules above is that a generic inner class of a raw type can itself only be used as a raw type.

That means that because `Hotel` is a raw type, every generic type inside it can also only be a raw type, i.e. `hotelOffers` is treated as if it were a raw `List` which allows any type of object (thus even this should work in your code `hotelObject.hotelOffers.add("I'm not a hotel offer");`)

Comment: Why does it disable the generic type check for the `hotelOffers` list? The list doesn't use the type parameter of the `Hotel` object. It will always be `List<HotelOffer>`.

Comment: Might want to add that by using `Hotel<String> = .. ` it will use the type check.

Comment: Does the compiler transitively disable the generic type check on every member of the object when using the raw type?

Comment: @marstran sorry, looked up the wrong section of the JLS. I'll add it later,

Comment: [Here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ007) is an explanation for that behavior from Angelika Langer.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to add a `BaseOffer` object (superclass) in a `List` of `FlightOffer` (subclass) objects.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

```
Flight flightObject = new Flight();
flightObject.flightOffers.add(new FlightOffer());    // that's correct
```

Comment: I think the weird part here is that the second example actually compiles (although with a warning).